# Android phone having micro SD card instead of soldered flash IC

Tags: rom-flashing, hardware, flashdrive

Do you know an Android phone that instead of a soldered on flash IC has a removable micro SD card and can boot from it?

I imagine how easy backup and unbricking could be if such a thing existed.

Comment: Usually Android devices use fast [UFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Flash_Storage) based flash storage for soldered storage. Even the oldest UFS 1.0 standard from 2011 is faster than 90% of all micro SD-cards. So actually nobody would buy a device without UFS storage.

Comment: Robert is right SD Cards are slow, one of the reasons I dislike the raspberry pi